# jquery chain actions

Tags: jquery

I would like to have a button on my page that scrolls to top of the page and then slides down a div.

this is what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".slidingDiv").hide();
        $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);
        $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle(500);
    });

});
```

the problem is that when the animate scrolltop ends the div have already slided, how can I chain the actions?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function takes a function argument, that can be called once the animation is complete.

> .animate( properties [, duration] [, easing] [, complete] )

- properties - A map of CSS properties that the animation will move
  toward.
- duration - A string or number determining how long the
  animation will run.
- easing - A string indicating which easing
  function to use for the transition.
- **complete - A function to call once the animation is complete.**

You can change your code to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000, 'linear', function(){
            $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle(500);
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [complete callback functionality](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#complete) of the animation function. This fired only when the animation has completed.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function() {
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 1000, function() {
            $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle(500);
        });
    });
});​
```

Here's a **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/U7Duj/)**.

> **Complete Function**
>
> If supplied, the complete callback function is fired once the
>   animation is complete. This can be useful for stringing different
>   animations together in sequence. The callback is not sent any
>   arguments, but this is set to the DOM element being animated. If
>   multiple elements are animated, the callback is executed once per
>   matched element, not once for the animation as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

Insert your SlideToggle in animate's complete callback like this

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000,function(){
            $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle(500);
        });

    });
```

check the [$.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) doc.

Comment: solved:

 $(document).ready(function(){
  
         $(".slidingDiv").hide();
         $(".show_hide").show();
  
     $('.show_hide').click(function(){
      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 800);
      $(".slidingDiv").delay(800).slideToggle(500);
     });
  
 });

Answer (score 0):

Using the queue functionality in jquery: http://api.jquery.com/queue/